# Plotly.js - Set ticks inbetween values

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to set some tick values on the x-axis but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do it.

Example of what I would like to achieve

1'''''100'''''1000

The `'` represents ticks in between our xvalues of interest. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet where you tried to achieve ? People won't  write code from scratch for you.

Comment: I wasn't looking for code, just a pointer in the right direction :p

Answer (score 2):

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    tickvals: [1,   10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000],
    ticktext: ["1", "tick", "tick", "tick", "tick", "tick", "100",  "tick",  "tick",   "tick",  "tick", "1000"]
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", [{x:[1, 10, 1000], y: [1, 1, 1]}], layout);
```

It is not clear what you're asking for; [here's](https://codepen.io/alanoc/pen/XgZWMg) an example of manual ticks, which are explained in [the documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickvals)

Comment: Cheers dude. I needed to set my tickmode to be an array and created a custom method which added a tick value for every 10 steps so all works :) This pointed me in the right direction!